# How do I read in a file line by line, and add the value of 5 to every instance of a dollar amount and write it to a new file

Tags: bash, replace

I am taking a rather large file which is basically a list of products sold in various quantities and I want to add a fixed number to every existing dollar amount mentioned in the file (so everything with a dollar sign in front of it, to make things even more confusing .)  The file contents are very predictable and are arranged as such:

```
16-point printed 2 side three and a half by two matte finish no round corners turn around 2-4 business days one set
250 $9.40 500 $11.05 750 $13.58 1000 $14.40 2500 $33.25 5000 $43.00 10000 $73.00 15000 $108.00 20000 $140.00 25000 $172.50
```

and that goes on until forever and a day. All I want to do is add lets say 5 bucks to each dollar amount, and spit out a new file. I am pretty sure that I want to evaluate it one word at a time, but entire lines can be totally skipped, due to quantities/values only appearing every second line. NOt all items have the same number of quantities so a fixed loop can't work.

I have been able to read and regurgitate the file, and I have played with reading single characters at a time.  but seeing as this script will be useful now and down the road, I want to do it right and I'm new to BASH.

I'm sure it will be a combination of

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r  line; do
for word in $line; do
    echo -n "'$word'"
done
done < "textfile.txt.bak"
```

and

```
n=1
while IFS= read -r "variable$n"; do
  n=$((n + 1))
done < textfile.txt

for ((i=1; i<n; i++)); do 
  var="variable$i"
  printf '%s\n' "${!var}"
done
```

I know I should be searching for the '/$' and reading in the numbers that follow, convert string to a real number, add 5, and then convert back to string, print a $ and the string, rinse wash repeat until next year.  I'm pulling my hair out trying to find the best way to approach it in Bash.
PLEASE HELP!
RJM

Comment: I'm curious why you chose `bash`. Of course you can do it, but for tasks like this bash will be harder to write and slower to execute than most other languages, e.g. `perl` or `python` (which can also be run directly from the console or another shell script).

Comment: I just figured I 'd give bash a shot because I never took the time to learn it and I'm on linux console practically all the time. I haven't used Perl since 1999. Kinda forgot it too. I thought I'd make something quick and dirty and maybe learn something... Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 4):

While possible in bash, I'd recommend to use something else. For example, in Perl it boils down to:

```
perl -pe 's/\$\K([0-9.]+)/sprintf "%.2f", $1+5/ge if /\$[0-9]/' -- file
```

- `-p` processes the input line by line, printing eachline after processing.
- `... if /\$[0-9]/` runs the `...` part if the current line contains a dollar sign followed by a digit.
- `/g` does a global replacement, i.e. all the possible occurrences.
- `/e` interprets the replacement as code.
- `\K` forgets what matched so far, in other words it only replaces the number, not the dollar sign.

Comment: Nice and concise. Can you explain some of the Perl-isms in the substitution? E.g. what's the -pe option, what's \K, and how is it that sprintf is recognized as a command (I think) and not as direct text replacement?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Updated.

Comment: That IS super simple..   I haven't used Perl in so long I almost forget how to spell it. Very good descriptions as well, Thank you very much! I will give that a try right away!

Comment: Worked like a charm and I did learn something after all (Like how bad my memory is). Hard to believe I used to program CGI for web in Perl for a living 20 years ago..   Amazing how easy to forget the subtle tricks over the years.

Comment: Thanks, great ! That adds a lot of value, presumably not only for me :-).

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty gnarly in bash due to the integer-only arithmetic

```sh
while read -ra words; do
    for i in "${!words[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${words[i]} =~ ^\$([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)? ]]; then
            printf -v words[i] '$%d%s' $((BASH_REMATCH[1] + 5)) "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        fi
    done
    echo "${words[*]}"
done < file
```

```
16-point printed 2 side three and a half by two matte finish no round corners turn around 2-4 business days one set
250 $14.40 500 $16.05 750 $18.58 1000 $19.40 2500 $38.25 5000 $48.00 10000 $78.00 15000 $113.00 20000 $145.00 25000 $177.50
```

To send to a new file, change the last line to

```sh
done < file > new.file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use awk for tnis task.

```
awk 'NR%2==0{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){split($i,a,"$");$i=sprintf("%s%.2f","$",a[2]+5)}}1' file
```